# selenium IDE javascript replace: Throw an exception: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, selenium, replace, selenium-ide

I wrote a test using selenium IDE, I need to compare two text that MAY contain the

character, if the strings are equal, it skips to a label. the comparison command

```
<td>gotoIf</td>
<td>'${var1}'=='${var2}'</td>
<td>skip</td>
```

works if the character above is not there, but fails with

> [error] Threw an exception: missing ; before statement` otherwise

I tried to write a replace statement supposed to replace ' with a blank space (since I don't care if is there or not):

```
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>javascript{storedVars.var1.replace("\'"," ");}</td>
<td>var1</td>
```

but it always fails with the same error as above.

what am I missing? can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took user extension js from [here](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/selenium-ide-gotoif-gotolabel-and-label.html). Can you try with **double quote** instead of **single quote** in `gotoIf` command? It works for me.  Please refer my screenshot below.

```
<td>gotoIf</td>
<td>"${var1}"=="${var2}"</td>
<td>skip</td>
```

[image]